# ODBC connecting to SQL Server PHP Error on a linux server

Tags: php, linux, odbc, sqlsrv

I'm trying to connect to a sql server but getting error of odbc not installed. But on my server odbc and sqlsrv extensions are installed for php. I'm using PHP 7.4.11 and ODBC 2.3.1.Please help.

This is the code I'm using to connect

```
$serverName = $serverIP; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$db, "UID"=>$user, "PWD"=>$pwd, "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo) ;

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

*Error msg I am getting is:*

```
Connection could not be established.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) )
```

I'm able to connect to the database via my local system using same code with xampp on windows

Comment: Are you trying to connect magically or do you maybe have some code to 
illustrate your connection?

Comment: @Explisam, Sorry I forgot to mention. Now I've edited my question please check

Comment: Post the exact error message given to you.

Comment: @Explisam sure.

Comment: Which version of PHP and ODBC are you using? Can you confirm they're both [compatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: The error message specifically states that as far as the PHP extension can tell, Microsoft's "ODBC driver for SQL Server" is not installed on the server where the PHP app is running. Is it?

Comment: @Explisam I'm using PHP 7.4.11 and ODBC 2.3.1. I'm not aware if they are compatible.

Comment: @GordThompson It is installed on the server.

Comment: What OS (name + version) is the server running?

Comment: @GordThompson It's Linux

Comment: Be more specific. Ubuntu 20.04? Debian 9? RHEL 8? …?

Comment: @GordThompson It's Linux us-imm-web433.main-hosting.eu 3.10.0-962.3.2.lve1.5.38.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 18 05:28:41 EDT 2020 x86_64

Comment: Does the folder `/opt/microsoft` exist on the server?

Comment: @GordThompson I'm not sure where to find this folder.

Comment: `/opt/microsoft` is an *absolute path* (it begins with `/`) so just try `ls /opt/microsoft` on the server and see if you get any results.

Comment: @GordThompson ls: cannot access /opt/microsoft: No such file or directory. This is what it returned.

Comment: Then it's very likely that the ODBC Driver for SQL Server has not been [installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) on the server.

Comment: @GordThompson Okay. It's a shared webhosting server and in phpinfo. it says odbc is installed and enabled. How do I install it then?

Comment: There must be other customers who want to connect their PHP sites to SQL server. Ask the support team for the web hosting service what you should use in that environment. BTW, phpinfo is telling you that it can communicate with ODBC drivers, not that any particular driver is installed.

Comment: @GordThompson I did talk to support team they told me they only support unixODBC 2.3.1 and FreeTDS drivers and If I need to upgrade it, the other option would be to use VPS also said the issue I'm facing is regarding development. So need developer's help and they can only assist me with hosting issues. That's why I'm here. Also they asked to create an odbc.ini file which has content like this: 
[mssql_odbc]
Description = MSSQL Server
Driver = FreeTDS
Database = sa_SermMTR2021
Server = 202.191.175.241
Port = 1433
which I did n tried to make connection with the database but it didn't work

Comment: For FreeTDS ODBC I think you'll need to use PDO_ODBC, not sqlsrv (which appears to be hard-wired to Microsoft's ODBC driver).

Comment: @GordThompson It worked. Thank you so much. :) Just one last thing I want to know, How do I use sql queries with this connection?

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeeded to make a database connection.
[This](https://zend18.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/218197897-Configuring-a-Linux-Server-to-Connect-to-an-MSSQL-Database-Using-ODBC) helped alot.
First of all I had to create a odbc.ini file in my home directory as I'm using a shared hosting to host multiple websites so this file is supposed to be placed in the main domain file manager.
Code in the file odbc.ini is(fill your server and database details accordingly):
`[mssql_odbc] Description = MSSQL Server Driver = FreeTDS Database =  Server =  Port = 1433`

Then I created another file in the domain directory where I need to connect to the SQL Server Database and tried to establish the connection using code:

```
// Replace the value's of these variables with your own data:
$dsn = "mssql_odbc"; // Data Source Name (DSN) from the file /odbc.ini
$user = "";     // MSSQL database user
$password = ""; // MSSQL user password

$connect = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $password);

//Verify connection
if ($connect) {
     echo "Connection established.";
     odbc_close($connect);
} else {
     die("Connection could not be established.");
}
```

and it worked.